# Set font/font size/font scaling for single application window

Tags: fonts, display-resolution, scaling, hdpi

**Background:**

On my high resolution display, some applications---e.g. Mendeley---do not scale nicely like native apps.

Currently, I scale up the entire app, using

```
 QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.2 mendeleydesktop
```

This works well, but also scales up the font. I would like to scale the font---*but only the font*---back down.

**Questions:**

*1:* Is there are command to run a single application with a given font size or font scaling?

*2:* Related, is there a command to run a single application with a given font? E.g., if I want to run Firefox with the interface text font set to `Ubuntu Italics` instead of the default `Ubuntu Regular`.

Answer (score 0):

Appropriate scaling for high DPI screens unfortunately is not standard. Ubuntu relies on GTK3 libraries. Any GTK3 application will adopt the system default settings and accordingly adapt properly to your high resolution display.

The application you refer to, Mendeley, uses the QT toolkit instead. Also that library had good HiDPI support, but it uses its own mechanisms and settings, independent from Ubuntu Desktop. You already discovered that QT5 applications can be scaled using environment variables. To reduce the size of fonts for this class of applications, install the application `qt5ct`. This is a settings panel that allows you to change, among others, the font size in QT5 applications.

This will work only for QT5 applications, not for applications that still use QT4 or any other toolkit. In some cases, no proper adjustment for high res displays is possible except from scaling the entire screen up using `xrandr`, which makes for a blurry appearance and blurry fonts.

Comment: I think you meant `xrandr`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Indeed, corrected. Thank you.